# SharePoint 2016 Calendar

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, calendar

I am using SharePoint 2016 Calendar.  I have a main calendar and 6 department calendars for visitors to my company.  I need to figure out how to have sharepoint add a visitor to the main calendar and to the department they are going to visit.  I am using the "Add" "New Item" to put the visitor on the calendar.  The divisions are check boxes in new item form

Answer (score 0):

To add the event to the specific department calendar, you can use a workflow.

When an event is created in the main calendar, trigger the workflow and create a same event in the specific calendar based on the value of divisions check boxes.

1. Create a Designer workflow for the main calendar using SharePoint Dessigner.
2. Automatically start the workflow when an item is created.
3. Use "If" condition to check the divisions.
4. If the dicisions checkbox contains `<department 1>`, use "Create List Item" action to create an item in the `<department 1>`. If the dicisions checkbox contains `<department 2>`, use "Create List Item" action to create an item in the `<department 2>`, and so on...
5. Set the new item values to the current item values.

[image]